# Include special characters in the load data MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to include some special characters in the load data.

My data in notepad is as below. This is just example, I have some extra special symbol like- ÿ ø

1|Test with special character 60ø

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_special_char_test`(
    `ID` int  NOT NULL,
    `Text` int NULL);
LOAD DATA INFILE 'G:/MYSQL_Load/Data_txt_files/dbPainTrax_BHF_V/L/test_m.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_special_char_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
 select * from tbl_special_char_test;
```

Load is getting failed with Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8mb4 character string. If I remove ø it is working, but I have lot of files and it is there more than one place.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: LOAD DATA allows to specify source CHARACTER SET option - do this according to your file charset.

Comment: Is `60ø` what you wanted?  Or gibberish that came out?  It sounds like Mojibake:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Thank you, which CHARACTER SET do I need to use for this kind of symbol.

Comment: Yes, it could be gibberish. Is there any way to avoid or allow this in LOAD Data.

Comment: How to remove this or include this symbol - ÿ